# Rails AJAX link_to occasionally responding with HTML show action (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, heroku

I have an issue where my Rails app in production (Heroku) will sometimes fail to update a resource attribute via AJAX and instead respond with HTML by redirecting to the show action. It works 90% of the time and the times it fails seems indistinguishable from the successful updates.

Here are the relevant parts of my files:

**_line_item.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to line_item_path(line_item, line_item: {packed: true} ), remote: true, method: :put, class: 'product-submit' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :line_items
```

**line_items_controller.rb**

```
 before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :set_order, only: [:update]

  def show
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.js
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_order
      @order = LineItem.find(params[:id]).order
    end
```

**line_items/update.js**

```
$('#line_item_<%= @line_item.id %>').parent().html('<%= j render 'line_items/line_item', line_item: @line_item %>');
```

Here are my logs from Heroku:
[The first request is PATCH and a success while the second is a GET request that fails to update the resource and responds with HTML to #show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsLA1.png)

Background:

- Can't replicate locally with MySQL
- Only happens on iOS Safari and Amazon Fire Tablet (one user has an Android phone and it never occurs)
- On Heroku Hobby plan with 10MM row upgraded db
- Anecdotally it only happens on the business's WiFi

My guess (hope) is I'm making a small syntax mistake with the link_to and the form is processed incorrectly / differently depending on the browser used.

Thanks for any assistance!

-Neal

Comment: You've only posted the `update` method's implementation. Where is the `show` method? The latter would be run for a `GET`.

Comment: Hi @SrdjanPejic, I added more of the controller. Let me know if that adds enough information. To be clear, it should never respond with a GET request and the different responses from the server came from identical links instances for each resource.

Comment: Can you also add what the rendered HTML looks for the first partial? That could rule out syntax errors.